# Get the Laravel's scheduled task executed parallelly

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I was optimizing my task scheduler as I'm gathering data from several different machines and I'm trying to start gather it at the same time.

In this below code on Kernel.php, will it executed parallelly? If not, how should I do it on "Laravel Way" (I'm using Linux server)

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $today = Carbon::today()->toDateString();

    $fingerprintMachines = FingerprintMachine::where('active', '1')->get();
    foreach( $fingerprintMachines as $fingerprintMachine)
    {
        //command to grab finger print database
        $schedule->command('fingerprint:grab '.$today.' '.$fingerprintMachine->id)
                 ->cron('5 5,10,19 * * *');
    }                                

}
```

Comment: The Laravel Scheduler [runs the tasks sequentially](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php#L54-L64). If you want to run them in parallel you could spin up multiple threads. Here's an article that [explains a possible approach](https://alfrednutile.info/posts/106) (it's written for an older Laravel version, but still it should give you an idea on how to implement this).

Comment: Thanks for the info Bogdan :) Sigh.. I guess I have to use queue with multiple worker.. In another note, if I execute 6 scheduled task with 1 minutes interval and each process takes 30 minutes, after 6 minutes, will all the task run parallelly?

Comment: If the tasks are scheduled to run at 1 minute intervals, then yes, because each time the scheduler cron job is run it spins up a new `schedule:run` command process.